# Select lines whose date-field is in a given month and year

Tags: postgresql, date

My SQL table looks like this:

```
id (int) | date (date) | text1 (varchar) | text2 (varchar)
```

I want to select the lines whose date suits a given month and year, regardless of the day.
Both month and year are given in the select-statement as integers.
So the missing thing is the where-clause. Perhaps `extract()` is the thing I'm looking for, but I don't know how to use it with the two integers, e.g. `2011` and `02`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use extract:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM "date") = 2
AND EXTRACT(year FROM "date") = 2011
```

But in this case you could also do this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE "date" >= '2011-02-01' AND "date" < '2011-03-01'
```

Comment: Ohh, i was totally focused on date-functions and didn't think about easy ways like your second one. Tanks!

Comment: you should not quote integer values. `extract()` returns a numeric value so it should not compared to a character value (which `'2'` is) but to a numeric value: `extract('month' from "date) = 2` is correct (and could make use of an index on that extract() expression)

Comment: Is there a considerable performance difference between those two solutions?

Comment: @Lennon - Without an index, the `>=` / `<` comparisons are somewhat faster; with a simple btree index on the date column, they are *much* faster. For the `extract` variant, you would need indexes on the `extract` expressions.