# How to delete records where timestamp equals 2018

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I'm having a Postgres database with a table `absences`. I'm trying to delete all records that have '2018' in their timestamp like this:

```
DELETE FROM absences WHERE date LIKE '%2018%';
```

but I get this error message:

```
absence-registrator_production=> DELETE FROM absences WHERE date LIKE '2018%';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown
LINE 1: DELETE FROM absences WHERE date LIKE '2018%';
```

Does anyone know how to delete records from the absences table that have '2018' in the date field?

Comment: `where extract(year from date) = 2018`? Or perhaps `where year(date) = 2018`?

Comment: Took me 2 seconds to google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052656/select-lines-whose-date-field-is-in-a-given-month-and-year

Comment: First comment shows the correct way to do it. However if you use `like` you need some text like casting as `date::varchar`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use a condition that could potentially make use of an index on that column:

```
where date >= timestamp '2018-01-01 00:00:00' 
  and date < timestamp '2019-01-01 00:00:00';
```

If you don't want to write a long "timestamp literal" and just pass a number to the query, you could use `make_timestamp()`

```
where date >= make_timestamp(2018,1,1,0,0,0) 
  and date < make_timestamp(2019,1,1,0,0,0);
```

If that value is a parameter you can use:

```
where date >= make_timestamp(?,1,1,0,0,0) 
  and date < make_timestamp(? + 1,1,1,0,0,0);
```

---

The extract function would work as well:

```
where extract(year from date)::int = 2018
```

or using to_char()

```
where to_char(date, 'yyyy') = '2018'
```

Comment: The first three methods would generally be preferable, because they allow the use of an index.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `date_trunc` is the easiest way:

```
WHERE date_trunc('year', date) = TIMESTAMPTZ '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
```

`extract` is also a nice idea, but it returns a `double precision`, and I feel nervous about comparing those with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I used this query to solve my problem:

DELETE FROM absences WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM "date") = 2018;